# connection between my database and remote computers

Tags: mysql, database, connection

> 1. I have a web page with database.
> 2. there are a lot of computers in all the world where is a specific software. This software do the same job (also save its data to local database. there are a lot of companies who produce this kind of software.

I would like to ask these companies to connect their software to my database. I will ask no users of these softwares, but companies, who created it. after it I suppose that they make an upgrade and users will use it.  how can I do this connection? I think write them my USER and PASSWORD of database is stupid. how to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, that would be unwise.  Create a REST API as a gatekeeper to allow the necessary access to the database.

Comment: Maybe just a form is enough? software fill the form and send

Comment: Like a web site form post?

Comment: yes. the work station will have its own 2 keys (for example 15 digits) and if it fill both and correct than form will be sent and saved. is it safe?

Comment: It is, of course, only as safe as the quality of the code.  If correctly implemented, using HTTPS, using prepared statements to prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities, with controls in place to prevent denial of service resulting from excessive traffic whether deliberate or due to popularity or a bug, and the logic is valid, then yes this is a much better and safer option than allowing direct access to your database, if I understand correctly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I once caught the attention of a major service provider when my implementation of the client-side component of something similar to this, due to a very simple error, failed to send the intended approximately 30 to 45 requests per hour, and instead, sent 40,000 requests per hour to their system.  For a couple of days.  The ultimate irony was that this was a regression introduced by a change that was actually intended to *reduce* the number of unnecessary requests.  So you have to anticipate things like this any time you expose a system.